# Check if all my workers are online in celery

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, celery

I have two workers running:

1. `celery -A project worker -Q OneAtTimeQueue -c1 -l Info`
2. `celery -A project worker -B -l info`

The first one is for making the task executing one at a time. Thats why it have concurrency of one.

And the second one is for the other tasks thats doesn't need to be one at time and its a beat for the periodic tasks.

When i use:

```
celery -A project status
```

it shows only:

```
celery@project: OK

1 node online.
```

How can i check if the two workers are online?

Answer (score 4):

First off, to spin up worker nodes without specifying names with `-n`, you will most likely get an `DuplicateNodenameWarning` warning like this:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/control.py:36: DuplicateNodenameWarning: Received multiple replies from node name: celery@hostname.

Secondly, you can use Celery Remote Command Ping to check all online workers(as they will respond with a `pong`), Ping command will broadcast pings to all Celery worker nodes and report back only the active ones, I.E.

```
$ celery -A project inspect ping
celery@hostname: OK
        pong
celery@hostname: OK
        pong
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/control.py:36: DuplicateNodenameWarning: Received multiple replies from node name: celery@hostname.
Please make sure you give each node a unique nodename using the `-n` option.
  pluralize(len(dupes), 'name'), ', '.join(sorted(dupes)),
```

Comment: Devy, I'm getting the `duplicatenodename` warning as well. Can you shed light on whether this produces any errors in task execution? Or is it something that can be ignored?

Comment: @HassanBaig DuplicateNodenameWarning is a warning not a fatal error so workers will run still. However, I would prefer to fix them. Basically, use the `-n` to specify node names so that they don't all default to the same name, just as noted in the error message.

Comment: Hmm I'm using supervisor to handle celery workers. I've defined `process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d` and `numprocs=5` in my celery.conf file. According to `supervisorctl`, the processes do have separate names. But are they all under the same celery 'node', is that what it is?

Answer (score 3):

[Celery Workers Guide](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#starting-the-worker) recommends using unique names when running multiple workers on a single host. Try adding the `-n` parameter and then running status:

```
celery -A project worker -Q OneAtTimeQueue -c1 -l Info -n worker1
celery -A project worker -B -l info -n worker2
celery -A project status
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i think the best is to use:

`ps aux | grep celery`

Then i can see if both processes are running.

Comment: This will only show information relevant to the machine you run it on. A common scenario for celery is to have workers running on remote nodes.

Comment: This won't tell you if the worker is online, better to use `app.control.inspect().active()`